# using macros to call event to write in excel using PHP

Tags: php, macros, xlsx

I am working on text transliteration (romanizing one lang text to another).

Input text is written in XLSX file.

What I want is, when user write text in one of the cell of xlsx file, it's transliteration(this I have worked out) should be written into it's neighborhood cell.

Is that possible to create `Macro` (or something else), so that when user write into one of the cell, event call occurs which performs it's transliteration and write it beside cell.

I worked out same for web application. Where user write into on text box, I perform action on `keyup` event and give result instantly in neighbourhood textbox.

```
$( "#english" ).keyup(function() { }
```

Is that any service to do this for xlsx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the VBA editor, Project explorer (left hand side by default), right click on the name of the sheet where the initial string will be entered and select "View Code". At the top of the editor window, there are two selection boxes. From the left one, select "worksheet", and from the right one, select whichever event you would like to have trigger your code. It sounds like you'd want either "Calculate" or "SelectionChange". Once you select that, the editor will populate the shell of a sub that you can fill with whatever code you need executed.